# Trying to run pry command in custom pry command

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm trying to customize my Pry a bit (been using Pry for a while but this is the first time I've tried to create a command.)  I want to create a custom command which will grab the last fifty items from my history and I'm building it like so:

```
Pry::Commands.block_command "fifty", "List the last fifty inputs" do
  hist --tail=50 -a
end
```

Once this is in my .pryrc file it does show if I do 'help fifty' but if I try to run the command I get the following:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for #<#<Class:0x007f8a1ee49aa8>:0x007f8a1e873ed0>
```

My guess is that there is some issue with how the command is scoped within the execution block but my search of the Pry documentation hasn't given me any ideas of how to proceed.  Other commands which don't try to replicate Pry cl commands such as the one from the example

```
Pry::Commands.block_command "hello", "Say hello to three people" do |x, y, z|
  output.puts "hello there #{x}, #{y}, and #{z}!"
end
```

work just fine.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: `hist --tail=50 -a` does not look like ruby code to me, are you trying to execute an external command as if ruby was a shell script language? If that's the case, you need to use backtick operators, or something like `system`. If this is a command as understood by pry itself, then you probably need to call some Pry API and pass the command as a string.

Comment: You're correct that it's not Ruby code, the Pry REPL has it's own scripting language which is what this is.  The documentation governing this isn't all that clear when it comes to putting these scripts into the command block (actual Ruby code works no problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing [`run`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Command-system#Custom_commands) which is required for running other `pry` commands:

```
Pry::Commands.block_command 'fifty', 'List the last fifty inputs' do |x|
  run 'hist --tail=50 -a'
end
```

Comment: And that worked like a charm!  Don't know how I missed that when I was setting this up, but the run method is the secret sauce I needed.  Can't thank you enough, you have no idea how much this is going to increase my productivity.